# ¿Por qué la data en base64 es distinto al enviar partes de un archivo existente con respecto a uno que no existe?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, pdf, socket

Node js. Estoy trabajando con socket-cluster generando pdf dinámicamente en el servidor con pdf-maker. Al crear el contenido del pdf ".createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition)" me devuelve un stream.

Actualmente estoy usando ese stream para crear un archivo, guardarlo, enviarlo y al terminar, eliminarlo. Sin embargo, quiero evitar crear el archivo enviando sólo la data del pdf y construyéndolo en el cliente.

Como los archivos son grandes lo que hago es construir un array y enviarlo por partes al cliente. El cliente conforme va recibiendo cada parte y evaluando que todavía no es la última parte va pidiendo la siguiente.

El problema sale cuando quiero convertir la data que me llega en base64 en un blob. Con la versión actual sí funciona, pero con la versión en desarrollo no.
He guardado en un archivo las respectivas datas en base64 y he notado que son iguales sino fuera por una diferencia que aparece periódicamente. 
En la data que sí puede transformar a blob contiene esto: o=ZW5kb2JqCg==
En la data que no puede transformar a blob contiene esto: plbmRvYmoK

Como repito, en lo demás es lo mismo.

No entiendo el porqué está generando datos distintos. 
El código en el lado del cliente es el mismo para ambas versiones:

```
var dataChunk = ''
socket.emit('DownloadPdf',data) // cualquier data para generar el pdf
socket.on('sendPdf', ({chunk,step,finish})=>{
    dataChunk += chunk
    if(step+1 < finish){
        socket.emit('ReceivedPdf', step+1)
    }else{
    var blob = b64toBlob(dataChunk,'application/pdf')     
    embed.setAttribute('src', URL.createObjectURL(blob) ) 
    //  Se renderiza exitosamente el pdf
    }
})
```

En la versión de desarrollo no logra convertir a blob con la función b64toBlob, específicamente porque salta el error de "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.". En la siguiente línea:

```
const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
```

Sin embargo, en la versión actual no bota ningún error y ejecuta hasta el final y renderiza exitósamente el pdf en el embed.

La versión del servidor actual es la que funciona guardando el archivo pdf en el sistema y luego enviándolo. Esta versión renderiza perfectamente el pdf en el cliente.
Versión del servidor actual:

```
socket.on('DownloadPdf', async (data,res) => {
    const dataChunk = []
    const sendPdf = step => {
        const chunk = dataChunk[step].toString('base64')
        socket.emit('sendPdf', { chunk, step, finish: dataChunk.length} )
    }
    const path = '/some/path'
    const pdfStream = await getPdfStream(data)  // genera pdf basado en 
    pdfmake.createPdfKitDocument(docdef) 

    pdfStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path))
    pdfStream.end()
    const pathStream = fs.createReadStream(path, 'base64') 

    pathStream.on('data', dataChunk.push )
    pathStream.on('end' , () => sendPdf(0) )

    socket.on('ReceivedPdf', sendPdf)
})
```

Versión del servidor en desarrollo:

```
socket.on('DownloadPdf', async (data,res) => {
    const dataChunk = []
    const sendPdf = step => {
        const chunk = dataChunk[step].toString('base64')
        socket.emit('sendPdf', { chunk, step, finish: dataChunk.length} )
    }
    const pdfStream = await getPdfStream(data)  // genera el pdf 

    pdfStream.on('data', dataChunk.push )
    pdfStream.on('end', () => sendPdf(0) )
    pdfStream.end() //  Sin esto no ejecuta el evento 'end'
    socket.on('ReceivedPdf', sendPdf)
})
```

Comment: Resulta confuso saber exactamente las diferencias entre la versión actual y la que tienes en desarrollo, edita tu pregunta y ponlas por separado, al menos los scripts del servidor.